# html syntax: json vs. javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, json

When storing html content, do json and js require a different html syntax?

For example here: the `'` and `+` in the below js object. My data is in a json array however, which seems slightly different.

I'm only familiar with using html data in an html doc and having a hard time finding info on this rudimentary stuff.

```html
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
      'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
      '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
      'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park.</p>'
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';
```

Comment: If you have a problem with a JSON array then you have to show us the array before can tell you what is wrong with it. (You should also show enough code and explain enough about the problem so we know what you are trying to do with the data and what is failing when you try). Just showing us some working JavaScript doesn't help us solve your problem!

Comment: `'` and `+` have nothing to do with "storing HTML" (or JSON). They are just string literal delimiters and concatenation operators in JS.

Answer (score -1):

For best practices you can can get the HTML code from a `template` tag that is present in the DOM, for example:

```
var contentString = $('#mydiv').html(); //with jquery
```

or

```
var contentString = document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML; //with vanilla javascript
```

And the `template` should have your infowindow template, like this:

```
<template id="myDiv">
  <div id="content">
    <!-- your infowindow html code goes here -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Why the `template` tag? Because it will be hidden for the user. If you want you can use a `div` tag or whatever with hidden styles.

Comment: thanks that's helpful, though I changed my initial question